# What's the difference between Powershell's New-Alias and Set-Alias cmdlets?

Tags: powershell

Other than `Set-Alias` being able to change extant aliases, what's the difference between these commands?

Why would someone use `New-Alias` over `Set-Alias`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One (the only one?) advantage in using `new-alias` is that you will get an error when you override an existing alias. Otherwise they are synonyms when it comes to alias creation, to quote from `help -full new-alias`:

> To create a new alias, use Set-Alias or New-Alias. To change an alias, use Set-Alias.